# update listview in fragment when returning to it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a Activity that transitions between fragments. Fragment 1 to fragment 2. Fragment 1 has a listview. When the user goes to fragment 2 the user has the option to make changes to the data that fills the listview. When the user presses the back button it takes them back to the first fragment. When the user returns the listview has to be updated to show the changes that were made in fragment 2. How can i do this?

```
            Frag2  pfrag = new Frag2();
            pfrag.setArguments(bundle);
            ft=fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_swap, pfrag,"Profile");

            ft.show(pfrag);

            ft.addToBackStack("pfrag");
            ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` on the ListView's adapter.

[For more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Robins answer or if you want to pass the data in fragment 2 to fragment 1 you could call a method in fragment 1 class:

`YourFragmentClass.refreshList( your data)`

and in Fragment 2 the method:

> puplic void refreshList(your data) {
>
> // set the adapter with your data
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

In you fragment, include the code as like below.

(isPaused)boolean variable is used to track current fragment is paused while navigating to next activity.

While resuming back call the webservice (or) call the method to refresh the list by calling notifydatasetchanged() from adapter.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(isPaused) {
            isPaused=true;
            fetchDirectories();  
    //      call the adapter method to notify the data set.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isPaused=true;
    }

    private boolean isPaused=false;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to achieve this, is to load the list in the fragment's onResume()-Method. So, the code looks something like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initializeList();
}

...

private void initializeList() {
    adapter = new MessageTemplateAdapter(getActivity(), datasource.getTemplateList());
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: @Robin- i tried that but the onResume of fragment 1 is not being called when i click back

Comment: Do you use fragmentTransaction.replace() or fragmentTransaction.add() when you call the fragment? Did you add the fragment to the backstack?

Comment: @Samantha: You should change "ft.add(R.id.fragment_swap, pfrag,"Profile");" into "ft.replace(R.id.fragment_swap, pfrag,"Profile"); - instead you really want to add the fragment in order to have more than one fragment in the container.